# Why doesn't Hydraulic pressure pull two cylinders apart?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics

Assume as simple hydraulic fixture as shown below.

Where the pipe or hose connects the two, there is a missing area on each cylinder. Wouldn't the hydraulic pressure then create an unbalanced force on each cylinder, one to the right and another the left, that would create tension and pull the hose/tube apart?

I know this doesn't happen but cannot for the life of me remember why. I know Pascals Principle but don't see how the forces would balance in this case.

Assume steady state/steady flow, the pressure is equal and no acceleration of fluid or rams

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that the hose is not firmly connected to the cylinder.  The pressure from the hose would create an unbalanced force on the cylinder.  It would accelerate away and the hose would pop off.

Since this doesn't happen, the hose connection must be strong and must be in tension during this event.  So the pressure onto the cylinder from the fluid in the hose is countered by tension from the hose itself.

Comment: I suppose this situation only exists IF the hose is perfectly straight. In most hyd applications, there might be a 90 deg fitting or something, and that would take that brunt, long before the hose would feel it. I guess i also started wonder if the oil itself inside the hose would act like a plug, balancing the system, since if at steady state, it is all under equal pressure.

Comment: It doesn't require it to be straight, just that the hose have sufficient tensile strength to keep from separating under the pressure.  And that is less than the hoop strength it needs to keep from bursting under the same pressure.

Comment: More I read, has to do with Pascals law. Since everything is under equal pressure and it is a closed system, there is no where for anything to go. The oil in the line is pressurized, so to the first cylinder, it acts rigidly keeping it balanced. Same with the other side. As a result energy transfers. While I agree there is some tension in the hose, it is the fact the oil is incompressible and under equal pressure everything must balance.

Comment: Exactly.  The pressure inside a vessel is borne by the wall strength of the vessel.  If you consider the system above to be a single vessel, the same is true.  If you consider the cylinder to be in isolation then you have to consider how the forces from the hose balance.  Any increase in pressure from the fluid is balanced by tension from the connection.

Comment: @KevinCSpeltz, "Compressibility" doesn't matter. The pressure of the fluid in the diagram will be the same everywhere when the system is in static equilibrium, regardless of whether the fluid is compressible or not. Where compressibility would make a difference is if we relaxed  the forces on the two pistons. If the fluid was compressible, then relaxing the pressure would mean an increase in volume (one or both of the pistons would have to move outward.) If incompressible, then the volume would be the same at any pressure.

Comment: @BowlofRed, not arguing, but I am curious why in practice we don't see the hose get really long. One would think the hose would stretch. However I suppose the hose is so rigid and crimped on the, the tension is not visible to the naked eye? Most hoses rated to 3k psi, not going to stretch like a balloon,  plus most of the time the cylinders are also not floating frictionless but locked down to a fixture

Comment: Longitudinal stress is usually less than hoop stress.  So if you overpressure, you probably start bulging before you start stretching.  https://www.engineersedge.com/material_science/hoop-stress.htm

Comment: @bowlofred, so ita happening, but since it bulges more, it's hard to see. Makes sense though as the entire hose stiffens up tell you it's under the pressure